# Google Fonts and ACF won't render åäö correctly in Firefox & IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, fonts, special-characters, advanced-custom-fields

I have searched around and could not find any answer to this åäö render bugs when I use Google Fonts (åäö is supported) and Advanced custom fields (ACF) for my website. [It looks like this, ignore that one is blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqn4D.jpg)

- Problem is only when ACF is printing the åäö.
- Problem is only for google fonts, I use PT serif.
- Problem is only in Firefox and IE
- When I "Inspect element" and add åäö to the same element, the added ones renders correctly.

Any ides of why this ain't working?

Comment: try this link https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: let me know if this work

Comment: Still the same problem unfortunately

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Okey, after ripping my hair out for a couple of days, I finally found the problem. The data was causing the trouble. And the combination of tools I used made it visible.

All my text was copied from a PDF straight into Advanced custom fields (in wordpress). So I presume that somehow the åäö was saved in some weird format, causing it to become two parts when saved in ACF. eg. A was separated from ¨

This only appeared in certain fonts on certain browsers for some odd reason.

So the solution is to rewrite the åäö or just copy all the text to a text editor and then into ACF again.

Hope this helps someone someday

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css, create the following 'new' font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Custom PT Sans';    
    src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ptsans/v6/jKK4-V0JufJQJHow6k6stALUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font URL is the same your browser uses when embedding the google webfont.

Get the URL here http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext

You may also rename your @font-face custom font-family alias.

Create a simple CSS rule to use that font targeting Browser/OS or both:

```
.mac .navigation a {    
    font-family: "Custom PT Sans", "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Or

```
.mac.webkit p {
    font-family: "Custom PT Sans", "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the rings and dotts on åäö is still rendered on the side of the letter.

Comment: The really weird part that has got my head spinning is that the bug ONLY appears when Advanced custom fields is printing the text AND I use google fonts.